# Why we pass View and context objects as parameter in function, API 22

Tags: android, view, this, android-context

I would like to know about this, also about 'this' as parameter

Answer (score 2):

> Within an instance method or a constructor, this is a reference to the
>   current object — the object whose method or constructor is being
>   called. You can refer to any member of the current object from within
>   an instance method or a constructor by using this.

and

You can get the current context by invoking `this` when in the activity class

Comment: Ask me If my answer is not upto your expectation

Comment: and what about View and Context

Comment: passing as parameter

Comment: context is kind of interface to the scope of the Object it might be activity or application .... you can access the objects resource using this.. we send view as parameter so that we can change the UI aspect of particular widget..

Comment: @sarah - If you have any doubt , plz do ask me